# How to get 'Chrome has detected insecure content' instead 'Chrome has detected either high-risk insecure content'

Tags: ssl, google-chrome-extension

I did extension to chrome.
When I browse to web site under https, My links still under http and I recieve:
**'The site uses SSL, but Google Chrome has detected either high-risk insecure content on the page or problems with the site’s certificate'**

I saw in other extension when I browse to web site under https, the links under http and they recieve:
**'The site uses SSL, but Google Chrome has detected insecure content on the page.'**

How can my extension recive 'insecure content' instead 'high-risk insecure content'?

Comment: Hard to tell if you dont post the relevant js

Answer (score 2):

This error occurs when the website content is only partially encrypted. Some of the sources for the page are coming from http sources. So basically if a website uses https all sources for https web pages must be https thus defeating the point of having the security. This is why web browsers at the very least show warnings or block the content